# Setting checkbox value based on a condition for dynamically generated input

Tags: angular

In my angular application I am trying to implement compare functionality between products. I have a list of products with a checkbox generated for each of them. Initially all the checkbox will be unchecked. When I click the checkbox of a product, I am checking if the total selected product to compare is not greater than 2. If it is greater than 2, the checkbox should become unchecked. I tried using the below code with no success. Any help on this is much appreciated.

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let att of displayProduct ">
   {{att.productName}}
   <input type="checkbox" name="att.productId" value="compare" 
   (change)="checkBoxClicked(att.productId)"
   [checked]= "test(att.productId)"> Compare
 </div>
```

TS:

```
compareList: string = [];
checkBoxClicked(val: string){
    if (this.compareList.length<2){
    this.compareList.push(val);
    }
    this.test(val);
}
test(val: string){
if (_.find(this.compareList, function(data ){return data == val }) === undefined){
    return false;
    }
    else {
    return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
  <div *ngFor="let att of displayProduct ">
   {{att}}
   <input type="checkbox" name="att" value="compare" 
   (change)="checkBoxClicked($event, att)"> Compare
 </div>
```

TS:

```
checkBoxClicked(e, value: string){
    if (this.compareList.length<2 && e.currentTarget.checked){     
        this.compareList.push(value); //adding checked value to the list     
    }
    else  if(!e.currentTarget.checked){
        var index = this.compareList.indexOf(value);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.compareList.splice(index, 1); //removing when unchecked
        }
      }
    else  
      e.currentTarget.checked = false;  //not selecting if list length > 2  
  }
```

Please find the inline comments.

Answer (score 0):

as angular is updating it is giving us lots of new features. you can use mat component to do these kinds of operations they are specially designed for this.

Please find below example:

HTML CODE

```
  <mat-list>
    <mat-list-item id="columnInfo" *ngFor="let att of displayProduct">
      <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" 
        (change)="$event ? prodSelection.toggle(att.id) : null" 
        [checked]="prodSelection.isSelected(att.productId)">
        {{ att.productName }}
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-list-item>
  </mat-list>
```

for TS file you can use SelectionModel a class specially designed for this kind of operations. Create an global variable as selection as:

```
  prodSelection = new SelectionModel<string>(true, []);
```

and refer it in HTML as I have mentioned in the example.
please refer this link [mat-checkbox](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview) for further clarification.